# Parse a YAML section using shell

Tags: awk, sed, yaml

I have a YAML that looks like

```
something:
 - whatever:
   - something
 - toc: 4
 - body: assets/footer.html
pkg:
 - pkg_a_1:
   - Shass
   - AJh55
   - ASH7
 - pkg_b_1:
   - Kjs6
   - opsaa
other:
morestuff:
 - whatever
```

I would like to pull out content under **pkg** and print them to a text file like this:

```
pkg_a_1 Shass
pkg_a_1 AJh55
pkg_a_1 ASH7
pkg_b_1 Kjs6
pkg_b_1 opsaa
```

I am trying to avoid using a full YAML parser as I only need this one section and nothing else from a large YAML file.

- The section label (**pkg**) is fixed, appears only once and does not change.
- The subsection label and the number of subsections (**pkg_a_1**, **pkg_b_1**) can change.
- The number of items and order of items under each subsection can change. Items can only contain `[A-Za-z0-9]+`.
- Content before and after the **pkg** section can change. ie; the sections **something:** and  **other:** may or may not be present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^[^ ]/{ f=/^pkg:/; next } f{ if (sub(/:$/,"")) pkg=$2; else print pkg, $2 }' file
pkg_a_1 Shass
pkg_a_1 AJh55
pkg_a_1 ASH7
pkg_b_1 Kjs6
pkg_b_1 opsaa
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

```bsh
yq -r '.pkg[] | to_entries[] | .key as $key | .value[] | [ $key, . ] | @tsv' file.yaml
```

This transforms the YAML data into a JSON document, which `yq` is able to use `jq` expressions to work with.

The expression converts the entries of `pkg` into a set of objects, like these:

```json
{
  "key": "pkg_a_1",
  "value": [
    "Shass",
    "AJh55",
    "ASH7"
  ]
}
{
  "key": "pkg_b_1",
  "value": [
    "Kjs6",
    "opsaa"
  ]
}
```

Each such object's `value` array is iterated over and an array with the `key` and the current `value` is converted into a tab-delimited list using the `@tsv` operator.

The final output, given the data in the question, is the tab-delimited list

```
pkg_a_1 Shass
pkg_a_1 AJh55
pkg_a_1 ASH7
pkg_b_1 Kjs6
pkg_b_1 opsaa
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also go with Mike Farah's [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), and `jq`:

```
yq -j r infile.yml 'pkg.*' |
jq -r 'to_entries[] | .key as $k | .value | map(. = $k + " " + .) | join("\n")'
```

Output:

```
pkg_a_1 Shass
pkg_a_1 AJh55
pkg_a_1 ASH7
pkg_b_1 Kjs6
pkg_b_1 opsaa
```